# Tag synonym: aspect-oriented to aop

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

It seems to me [aspect-oriented](/questions/tagged/aspect-oriented) is identical to [aop](/questions/tagged/aop). There [has been one synonym request already](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/aop/synonyms), but unfortunately I can't up vote it yet.

The explanation of [aspect-oriented](/questions/tagged/aspect-oriented) (107 tags) seems quite vague to me:

> Aspect oriented refers to the expression of event-driven programming
>   through the use of callback functions or other means to respond to a
>   local event that has global consequences without going through
>   repetitive conditional checks or creating uneccessary dependencies
>   between objects or subroutines.

The description of [aop](/questions/tagged/aop) (1106 tags) makes more sense to me:

> AOP stands for Aspect-Oriented Programing. A programming paradigm that
>   aims to increase modularity by allowing the separation of what are
>   called "cross-cutting concerns" (aspects).

Even if [aspect-oriented](/questions/tagged/aspect-oriented) would describe something else, looking at its usage clearly indicates many people would be misusing it.

I suggest making [aspect-oriented](/questions/tagged/aspect-oriented) a synonym of [aop](/questions/tagged/aop) and merging the two.

Comment: The same argument could be made for [tag:aspects].

Answer (score 1):

*If* the are synonyms, i.e. [aop](/questions/tagged/aop) isn't used for anything else (I don't know) I believe these should be merged the other way around.

I don't see any benefit in making a tag less easy to read and a better tag wiki should not be a reason to choose one tag over another. You can always edit the wiki and copy and paste the better into the worse. Even better, you could merge the best bits of the two.

In short; if [aop](/questions/tagged/aop) is a synonym of [aspect-oriented](/questions/tagged/aspect-oriented) then make [aspect-oriented](/questions/tagged/aspect-oriented) the main tag and merge [aop](/questions/tagged/aop) into it. Pick the best tag wiki and use your ability to suggest edits.

Comment: It seemed more in line with [tag:oop] to me. Additionally, given the statistics I would claim that people aware of [tag:aop] tend to use it more. And ... as a final remark, [tag:aop] implies it's a programming paradigm. [tag:aspect-oriented] does not convey that.

Comment: As a counter-argument, it can be misinterpreted to mean agent oriented programming. E.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5216865/590790) had [tag:aop] applied to it.